# Script.PostDeployment.sql not executing in CI build VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I have a database project in VS 2010 (SQL 2008).  The local `Deploy Solution` action works and executes all of the SQL in the `Script.PostDeployment.sql` file.  When I check changes in, the `Build Definition` for the continuous integration server executes.  The database is deployed into the CI environment, but the PostDeployment script doesn't get executed.

I wasn't able to find anything specific to this particular scenario.  I also expect I'll need to provide additional information unless this is a trivial problem that I missed somewhere.

**Additional Information:**

- The build is executing vsdbcmd.exe to deploy.
- The deployment manifest references the PostDeployment.sql file and it's present in the path with the rest of the files.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/6b2791d8-fbb4-4a44-9177-492bd367af69?prof=required) is a reference to a thread on social.msdn.microsoft.com regarding this problem.

Comment: Have you checked that the CI server has access to the path that the post deployment script is found at?

Comment: Yes, all of the artifacts including the postdeployment script are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the VSDBCMD was not referencing the deployment manifest.  The /manifest flag was added to the VSDBCMD and the PostDeployment.sql file was executed.